# Cordova .. Android Box , access USB flash storage

Tags: android, cordova

I am using cordova on Android Box and I try to access external USB flash memory connected but no luck

I used all these paths but no luck they all threw code 5 error in file system request

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///storage/usbdisk/", gotFS, failrequestFileSystem);
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///storage/UsbDriveA/", gotFS, failrequestFileSystem);
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///storage/usb0/", gotFS, failrequestFileSystem);
 indow.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///storage/usbdisk0/", gotFS, failrequestFileSystem);
```

if anyone could tell me the correct path I should provide or another method I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Paths to external storage locations are variable depending on Android version and device.

You can use [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) from [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to list the available external storage paths and resolve it from there.

Comment: Thanks Dave , i will try this now then get back to you

Comment: Note that you need run-time permission to access external storage on Android 6+ - see requestExternalStorageAuthorization() of that plugin

Comment: i used the example code in plugin and it gave me granted authorization for external storage , butgetExternalSDCardDetails ran  error callback method with error string arg == null , Any help ?

Comment: Try building+running the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example): use it to request external storage permission and get details on your target device.

Comment: Okay now it runs with no errors but it gives me no details for the flash memory attached to the box. it seems not recognizing it as external SD card , Now what ?

Comment: If that function doesn't detect it, then it isn't visible via the Android APIs that the plugin in using. You'll have to figure another way e.g. find and hard-code the absolute path manually.

Comment: Thanks Dave i appreciate you effort , one last thing , would you please suggest a way to determine the path of the USB flash memory storage so that i can hard code it ?

Comment: Connect device to PC and use adb: `adb shell ls /storage`

Comment: /dev/bus/usb/001/004 . This is the url for the usb file i get , how can i connect using this ?